# Sending Proactive Messages on Microsoft Teams with Bot framework

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, botframework, microsoft-teams

I installed a chatbot on Teams built with a bot framework. I am using Azure DevOps to update changes to the bot.

I want to send proactive messages to users following this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#avoiding-401-unauthorized-errors) and [example code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages). But I don't know how to call the /api/notify endpoint.

How can I call the https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/notify from within my code to send proactive messages to users on Teams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I don't like about this sample is that it makes it seem like you need to host the -ability- to make a pro-active call inside the same web host as your bot itself, which is definitely not required. You could, for instance, have your bot hosted in web application, but make a pro-active call from an Azure Function directly. That's one of the reasons I put together a different sample - check it out [here](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/bot-proactive-messaging). It requires only a service url (because the endpoint can change based on the tenant's geography, for instance) and a "conversation id" so that it know which user/group/channel to message to. Please check it out and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Hilton. The bot has already been installed on Teams and I didn't remember to store user info when these methods OnMembersAddedAsync and OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync were called. Though I still make updates to the bot via Azure DevOps continuous delivery. I have later implemented the proactive messages into the bot. When I push my updates, the bot didn't send the messages. My challenge here is how to visit the /api/notify endpoint on Teams because this is working with Bot emulator.

Comment: Just as you created a tab on Teams to send the proactive message, is there nowhere in code I can invoke the method to send the message when next I push updates via Azure CD? Since OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync and OnMembersAddedAsync are only called once when a user is added or at the moment the bot is installed on Teams. Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: The -best- place to get the require info is OnConversationUpdateActivityAsync / OnMembersAddedAsync , because then you're getting it straight away, and without requiring any user involvement. However, the info you need (service url and conversation id) come with -every- message, so any time the user message the bot, you can get them. Basically, just add the code to the regular message handler to get them, and then message your bot.

Comment: This works, @Hilton. But the bot keeps sending a proactive message every time the user message the bot. Any idea how I can make the bot send the message once when I add the code to the regular message handler?

Comment: well, I don't know what your code looks like, but you certainly don't want to -send- the proactive message every time, you just want to try get the conversation id and service url for later use. In fact, now that you have them, you can probably revert back to the previous code.

Comment: sure thing, glad to help

Comment: For anyone reading this, @HiltonGiesenow comments here are spot on. You may want to read his comments too if you get stuck.